# PHP Variable not outputting in full

Tags: php, forms, email, post

I'm working in PHP and I have a simple shopping cart which adds items when you click the add button.

Everything is collected in a variable called $cartOutput

When I echo it, it gives me everything in the cart as expected. Same with var_dump . Everything is there

**However, when I try to put it in an email and send it off. It cuts off the first item. Can anyone think of why this might be?**

Nothing filters it before it is put into the email. It is simply what is in the variable

here is an example...

```
// e.g of the php variable being assembled for each item
    $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
    $cartOutput .= "<td>" . $product_name . "</td>";
    $cartOutput .= "<td>$" . $price . "</td>";
```

// emailing the variables off here

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {

    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $commercialAdd = $_POST['commercial'];
    $residentialAdd = $_POST['residential'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];
    $postal_code = $_POST['postal_code'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $special_instructions = $_POST['special_instructions'];

    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    $time = date("h:i:sa");
    $to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $header = "Cc:xxx@somedomain.com \r\n";
    $subject = "Email Order - $company ($date - $time)";
    $message = <<<EOD
        <h1>Email Order - $date - $time </h1>
        <h3><strong><u>Company:</u></strong> $company</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Name:</u></strong> $Name </h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Address:</u></strong> $address<br>
        $address2</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Residential:</u></strong> $commercialAdd </h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Commercial:</u></strong> $residentialAdd </h3>
        <h3><strong><u>City:</u></strong> $city</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Province:</u></strong> $province</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Postal Code:</u></strong> $postal_code</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Phone Number:</u></strong> $phone</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Email:</u></strong> $email</h3>
        <h3><strong><u>Special Instructions:</u></strong> $special_instructions</h3>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Weight (Kg)</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
                $cartOutput
                <tr>
                    <td class="totals"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                    <td class="totals">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="totals">$weightTotal kg</td>
                    <td class="totals">$quantityTotal</td>
                    <td class="totals">$ $cartTotal</td>
                    <td class="totals">&nbsp;</td>
                <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
EOD;
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if( $retval == true ) {
    header("location: complete.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    echo "Order could not be sent. Please try again or contact our office for assistance";
}

}
```

Comment: is that a typo? `$cartOutput` is missing single quotes inside the `<tbody>`

Comment: Also, is `.=` a thing? I am not familiar with that syntax

Comment: Post the actual code that is causing the problem. Also post the exact error(s) or output you are getting.

Comment: .= is  concatenation adding (or whatever that would be called.. haha)
The variables are being called within the php email message. I don't need to echo or use quotes to use the variable as far I know.. everything else is being evaluated properly.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I included the full email example... I don't get any error that shows. Just that upon receipt of the email, I don't get everything in cartOutput. All items except the first one..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running into an email format issue. [`mail()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php) requires the body to end each line in \r\n AND be less than 70 characters each. You will need to encode you HTML or include it as an attachment. See [this set of instructions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) for an example.

Comment: i was also looking at using a (3rd party?) mailing script that some ppl have mentioned. have you ever used one or can recommend?

Comment: I use the one that is built into CodeIgniter, it works great.